# How do I enter pdb debugger when the datastore is started in setUp(unittest.TestCase)?

Tags: google-app-engine, selenium, pdb, python-unittest

I'm confused. It would seem that Client entity should exist because I have 2 locations for it to be created:
I create the requested Entity in the the setUp() of the unittest.TestCase.
I also conditionally create the Client entity in main.py if it doesn't exist already.

I have tried to set a breakpoint where the Client entity is called, but **I can't step into the debugger**.  While the code stops execution, I can't step into the debugger. I'm not even sure how to see the output.

I set the Consistency policy to 1, so the record should exist.
datastore_stub_util.PseudoRandomHRConsistencyPolicy(probability=1)

$ nosetests

```
INFO     2015-02-24 19:08:56,172 devappserver2.py:726] Skipping SDK update check.    
INFO     2015-02-24 19:08:56,242 api_server.py:172] Starting API server at: http://localhost:62049    
INFO     2015-02-24 19:08:56,247 dispatcher.py:186] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080    
INFO     2015-02-24 19:08:56,249 admin_server.py:118] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000    
ERROR    2015-02-24 19:09:00,307 webapp2.py:1552] 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'key'    
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "/Users/Bryan/Desktop/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__    
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)    
  File "/Users/Bryan/Desktop/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__    
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)    
  File "/Users/Bryan/Desktop/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher    
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)    
  File "/Users/Bryan/Desktop/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__    
    return handler.dispatch()    
  File "/Users/Bryan/work/GoogleAppEngine/dermalfillersecrets/main.py", line 18, in dispatch    
    webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)    
  File "/Users/Bryan/Desktop/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch    
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)    
  File "/Users/Bryan/Desktop/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch    
    return method(*args, **kwargs)    
  File "/Users/Bryan/work/GoogleAppEngine/dermalfillersecrets/main.py", line 95, in get    
    self.session['client'] = client.key.urlsafe()    
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'key'    
INFO     2015-02-24 19:09:00,314 module.py:737] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 2354    
INFO     2015-02-24 19:09:00,377 module.py:737] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 8348    
INFO     2015-02-24 19:09:00,381 module.py:737] default: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 304 -    
EINFO     2015-02-24 19:09:08,482 shutdown.py:45] Shutting down.    
INFO     2015-02-24 19:09:08,483 api_server.py:588] Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore    

======================================================================    
ERROR: test_guest_can_submit_contact_info (dermalfillersecrets.functional_tests.NewVisitorTest)    
----------------------------------------------------------------------    
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "/Users/Bryan/work/GoogleAppEngine/dermalfillersecrets/functional_tests.py", line 88, in test_guest_can_submit_contact_info    
    self.browser.find_element_by_name('id_name').send_keys("Kallie Wheelock")    
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 302, in find_element_by_name    
    return self.find_element(by=By.NAME, value=name)    
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 662, in find_element    
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']    
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 173, in execute    
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)    
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response    
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)    
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"id_name"}    
Stacktrace:    
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///var/folders/mw/0y88j8_54bjc93d_lg3120qw0000gp/T/tmpSjWZ6W/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:9641:26)    
    at fxdriver.Timer.prototype.setTimeout/<.notify (file:///var/folders/mw/0y88j8_54bjc93d_lg3120qw0000gp/T/tmpSjWZ6W/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:548:5)
```

Here is the code in functional_tests.py

```
import sys, os, subprocess, time, unittest, shlex      
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine")       
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib")       
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2")       
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5")       
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy")       
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/concurrent")       
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/docker")       
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/requests")       
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/websocket")       
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib")       
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/antlr3")       

from selenium import webdriver       
from google.appengine.api import memcache, apiproxy_stub, apiproxy_stub_map      
from google.appengine.ext import db       
from google.appengine.ext import testbed       
import dev_appserver         
from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import devappserver2       


class NewVisitorTest(unittest.TestCase):       

    def setUp(self):       
        # Start the dev server        
        cmd = "/usr/local/bin/dev_appserver.py /Users/Bryan/work/GoogleAppEngine/dermalfillersecrets/app.yaml --port 8080 --storage_path /tmp/datastore --clear_datastore --skip_sdk_update_check"       
        self.dev_appserver = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd),      
                                              stdout=subprocess.PIPE)     
        time.sleep(2) # Important, let dev_appserver start up     

        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()   
        self.testbed.setup_env(app_id="dev~myapp")       
        self.testbed.activate()       
        #self.testbed.setup_env(app_id='dermalfillersecrets')       
        self.testbed.init_user_stub()       
        # Create a consistency policy with a probability of 1,  
        #  the datastore should be available.  
        self.policy = datastore_stub_util.PseudoRandomHRConsistencyPolicy(probability=1)  
        # Initialize the datastore stub with this policy.  
        self.testbed.init_datastore_v3_stub(datastore_file="/tmp/datastore/datastore.db", use_sqlite=True, consistency_policy=self.policy)       
        self.testbed.init_memcache_stub()       
        self.datastore_stub = apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.GetStub('datastore_v3')     

        # setup the dev_appserver       
        APP_CONFIGS = ['app.yaml']       

        # setup client to make sure      
        from main import Client      
        if not ( Client.query( Client.name == "Bryan Wheelock").get()):     
            logging.info("create Admin")     
            client = Client(     
            email = "bryan@mail.com",     
            name = "Bryan Wheelock",     
            street1 = "555 Main St",     
            street2 = "unit 1",     
            city = "Atlanta",     
            zipcode = 99999,     
            phone = "(888)555-1212"     
            ).put()  
            # this sleep is to allow eventual consistency to propogate     
            time.sleep(2)

        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()       
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)       

    def tearDown(self):       
        self.browser.quit()       
        self.testbed.deactivate()       
        self.dev_appserver.terminate()     

    def test_guest_can_submit_contact_info(self):      
        from main import Client, Customer        
        client = Client.query( Client.name == "Bryan Wheelock").get()       
        orig_customer_count = Customer.query(ancestor=client.key).count()       
        self.browser.get('http://localhost:8080')     
        time.sleep(5)     
        self.browser.find_element_by_name('id_name').send_keys("Kallie Wheelock")       
        self.browser.find_element_by_name('id_street').send_keys("123 main st")       
        self.browser.find_element_by_name('id_phone').send_keys('(404)555-1212')       
        self.browser.find_element_by_name('id_zip').send_keys("30306")       
        self.browser.find_element_by_name('submit').submit()       
        # the time delay is to allow eventual consisenency to happen.     
        time.sleep(4)       
        assert(Customer.query(Customer.name == "Kallie Wheelock").get())     
        # this should return 1 more record     
        final_customer_count = Customer.query(ancestor=client.key).count()       
        self.assertNotEqual(orig_customer_count, final_customer_count)       

        # Delete the Customer record       
        Customer.query(Customer.name =="Kallie Wheelock").delete()
```

Here's the code in main.py:

```
import os    
import urllib    
import logging    

from google.appengine.api import users    
from google.appengine.ext import ndb    

import jinja2    
import webapp2    
from webapp2_extras import sessions    

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):    
    def dispatch(self):    
        self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)    

        try:    
            # dispatch the request    
            webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)    
        finally:    
            # save all sessions    
            self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)    

    @webapp2.cached_property    
    def session(self):    
        # Returns a session using the default cookie key.    
        return self.session_store.get_session()    

JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(    
    loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),    
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],    
    autoescape=True)    

DEFAULT_LEADBOOK_NAME = 'whatsmyname'    

def leadbook_key(leadbook_name=DEFAULT_LEADBOOK_NAME):    
    """Constructs a Datastore key for a LeadBook entity with leadbook_name."""    
    return ndb.Key('LeadBook', leadbook_name)    



class Client(ndb.Model):    
    email =  ndb.StringProperty()     
    name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)    
    street1 = ndb.StringProperty()    
    street2 = ndb.StringProperty()    
    city = ndb.StringProperty()    
    zipcode = ndb.IntegerProperty()    
    phone = ndb.StringProperty()    
    signup = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)    

# this just creates a Client to use    
if not ( Client.query( Client.name == "Bryan Wheelock").get()):    
    client = Client(    
    email = "bryan@mail.com",    
    name = "Bryan Wheelock",    
    street1 = "555 Main St",    
    street2 = "unit 1",    
    city = "Atlanta",    
    zipcode = 99999,    
    phone = "(888)555-1212"    
    ).put()    



class Customer(ndb.Model):    
    # I commented out client property because using Ancestor Query( limited to 1 write per second)    
    #client = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Client)    
    #email = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)    
    name = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)    
    street1 = ndb.StringProperty()    
    street2 = ndb.StringProperty()    
    city = ndb.StringProperty()    
    zipcode = ndb.IntegerProperty()    
    phone = ndb.StringProperty()    
    signup = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)    

class MainPage(BaseHandler):    
    def get(self):    
        leadbook_name = self.request.get('leadbook_name',    
                                            DEFAULT_LEADBOOK_NAME)    

        # This record should exist because I create in setUP and in main.py   
        client = Client.query( Client.name == "Bryan Wheelock").get() 
        ###########################################################  
        ########################   
        # I can't step into the debugger because I don't know how to access debugger shell.  
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()  
        ########################
        ###########################################################
        self.session['client'] = client.key.urlsafe()    

        template_values = {    
            'client': client,    
            'leadbook_name': urllib.quote_plus(leadbook_name),    
        }    

        template = JINJA_ENVIRONMENT.get_template('index.html')    

        self.response.write(template.render(template_values))    

class LeadBook(BaseHandler):    
    def post(self):    
        leadbook_name = self.request.get('leadbook_name',    
                                          DEFAULT_LEADBOOK_NAME)    

        client = ndb.Key(urlsafe=self.session['client']).get()    

        customer = Customer( parent = client.key)    
        customer.name = self.request.get('id_name')    
        customer.street1 = self.request.get('id_street')    
        customer.phone = self.request.get('id_phone')    
        customer.zipcode = int(self.request.get('id_zip'))    
        # show original number of customer to show the code works    
        starting_customer_count = Customer.query(ancestor=client.key).count()      
        customer.put()    
        # This should return the record    
        assert(Customer.query(Customer.name == "Kallie Wheelock").get())     
        final_customer_count = Customer.query(ancestor=client.key).count()    
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()    
        query_params = {'leadbook_name': leadbook_name}    
        self.redirect('/?' + urllib.urlencode(query_params))    

config = {}    
config['webapp2_extras.sessions'] = {    
    'secret_key': 'my-super-secret-key',    
}    
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([    
    ('/', MainPage),    
    ('/sign', LeadBook),    
], config = config,    
    debug=True)
```

Comment: Are you using nosetest to run the tests?

Comment: Yes. I've also tried using nosetests --with-gae which give a different error but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you use nosetests, try running it with the `pdb` option.

```
nosetests -sv --pdb
```

The --pdb option will drop the test runner into pdb when it encounters an error.

More info here:
http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/debug.html

Comment: I tried nosetests -sv --pdb;   I put an ssert(client.key) before the line where I convert it to a URLsafe key

Comment: File "/Users/Bryan/work/GoogleAppEngine/dermalfillersecrets/main.py", line 86, in get      
    assert(client.key)   
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'key'

Comment: Breakpoint happens here: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py(166)check_response()

Comment: @BryanWheelock Isn the question about stepping into the debugger on a failure? From what I read from your comments, seems like it does successfully enter the debugger, but now you are asking how to fix the error?

Comment: You technically answered my question, but I'm trying to step into my code to diagnose the reason for the error I'm getting.

Comment: You can see the import pdb; pdb.set_trace() in the main.py code.
That's where I was attempting to use the debugger.